# Sitecore : Right click feature for a specific div class inside RTE

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, rich-text-editor

I'd like to know whether it's possible for a specific `div` class to have a right click feature similar to how Sitecore image and Sitecore link currently have.

[image]

Because I'm inserting in an image with caption text eg:

```
<div class="embeded-image inline-image-left">
  <img src="/img/generic-image.jpg" style="max-width: 220px;">
  <div class="inline-caption">[ Type in your image caption here ]</div>
</div>
```

And I would like to be able to right click on my caption `div` and easily change the caption text property.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this control need to be in an RTE field? Can you not have separate fields in your item for each part, or do you need to truly insert this stuff randomly? How are you inserting the markup into the RTE, this level of DOM elements is not something that your average content editor would add into the RTE themselves.

Comment: BTW, those right click menus do not work in the Page Editor, only in the popup RTE control.

Comment: Hi Jammykam, we currently have a snippet that inserts the image with caption inside the rich text editor.. its good for a one time insert.. but if they want to change the caption.. users find it hard to edit it the second time around... that's why i want the right click feature so tat user can easily change the caption

Comment: Sitecore uses an implementation of the Telerik RadEditor. Your best bet is to look at their support pages to figure out how you can implement this. I'm pretty sure it's possible.

Comment: I can think of another way of achieving something similar, are you open to suggestions to doing it a different way, or are you specifically looking for solution using the right click?

Comment: Thanks Ruud van Falier. Will try to asin Telerik forums.

Comment: Hi Jammykam, the right click feature is what we want. the other option would be to modify sitecore image right-click properties popup.           What is the other solution you're proposing?